# Use extrapolation/interpolation to resize an array

Tags: python, arrays, resize, interpolation, reshape

I have an array in the shape `(22, 48)` and I'm comparing it to another array with shape `(881,1121)`. In order to compare them I would like the shapes to map. I figured I could to do this in python using a form of extrapolation/interpolation, but I can't seem to find anything that would do it without simply filling the array with zeros or repeated values.

Is there a simple function that would do it for me or another method to do it?

**Edit 1:**

By compare, I mean I'm doing further analysis after they've been resized. Specifically, finding a skill score using the mean square error, which means I need them to be the same size/shape.

Comment: why not just compare two tuples, why won't it work?

Comment: I'm not really familiar